# Can I set the Recharts axis domain max lower than dataMax?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm using Recharts in a setting where users will want to see the same data plotted at different scales.  In particular, I need to be able to set the axis domain maximum to be **lower** than the maximum data value (`dataMax`); *e.g.*, I want to set `domain={[0,10]}` when `dataMax` is 20.  I have yet to find a way to do this in Recharts; whenever I set a domain maximum that is lower than `dataMax`, my plot is drawn so that the domain goes up to `dataMax` anyway.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

I've found a way to do this.  You need to use the functional syntax, which I had already tried, but **without any reference to dataMax in the function**.  So this is what worked for me:

```
domain={[ 0, dataMax => (10) ]}
```

You can of course use more elaborate code inside the parentheses; the trick is that you **cannot** use the dataMax variable in any way that reduces its value.  That is, you can't use, say `dataMax => (dataMax/2)` or `dataMax => (dataMax - 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

Set `allowDataOverFlow={true}`. This will show only points which are specified within your set domain. `domain={[0,10]}` will then work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to compare between two numbers

```
(dataMax: number) => Math.max(100, dataMax)]
```