# Prevent rechart from overflowing into margin?

Tags: recharts

I would like to display the most recent N points, but the chart overflows to the left when set the domain to anything less than `chartData.length`.

I see that I can shift everything to the left by adding `margin={{left:59}}` to `<ComposedChart>`, but that seems a little hacky.  Is there a better way to hide this overflowing line?

[image]

```
  /*
   * NOTE: the axis `domain` requires a _function_ if you want to display less than the total number of
   * data points (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751564/can-i-set-the-recharts-axis-domain-max-lower-than-datamax)
   */
  const pointsToDisplay = 8;
  const xAxisStart = chartData.length - pointsToDisplay;
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer height={210}>
      <ComposedChart data={chartData}>
        <XAxis dataKey="index" tick={true} type="number" domain={[() => xAxisStart, 'dataMax']} />
        <YAxis tick={false} domain={['dataMin - 3', 'dataMax + 3']} />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="score" strokeWidth={5} dot={false} stroke="var(--accentColor)" />
      </ComposedChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis) *allowDataOverflow* has to be set to true for the data to be clipped. You can then also remove the function from the domain array and simply use the variable:

```
/*
   * NOTE: the axis `domain` requires a _function_ if you want to display less than the total number of
   * data points (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751564/can-i-set-the-recharts-axis-domain-max-lower-than-datamax)
   */
  const pointsToDisplay = 8;
  const xAxisStart = chartData.length - pointsToDisplay;
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer height={210}>
      <ComposedChart data={chartData}>
        <XAxis dataKey="index" tick={true} type="number" domain={[xAxisStart, 'dataMax']} allowDataOverflow={true}/>
        <YAxis tick={false} domain={['dataMin - 3', 'dataMax + 3']} />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="score" strokeWidth={5} dot={false} stroke="var(--accentColor)" />
      </ComposedChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
```